# Not able to catch gridview exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I am trying to catch exception while updating a gridview.
code is

```
public static int UpdateProduct(
                             int productID,
                             string productName,
                             int supplierID,
                             int categoryID,
                             string quantityPerUnit,
                             decimal unitPrice,
                             int unitsInStock,
                             int unitsOnOrder,
                             int reorderLevel,
                             bool discontinued)
    {
        int rowsAffected = 0;

        using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetNorthwindConnection())
        {
              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ttUpdateProduct", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = productName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = supplierID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = categoryID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@QuantityPerUnit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = quantityPerUnit;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.Money).Value = unitPrice;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UnitsInStock", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = unitsInStock;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UnitsOnOrder", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = unitsOnOrder;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ReorderLevel", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = reorderLevel;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Discontinued", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = discontinued;

                rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }
        return rowsAffected;
    using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectionManager.GetNorthwindConnection())
        {
              SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ttUpdateProduct", connection);
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                command.Parameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = productID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 40).Value = productName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@SupplierID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = supplierID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@CategoryID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = categoryID;
                command.Parameters.Add("@QuantityPerUnit", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = quantityPerUnit;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", SqlDbType.Money).Value = unitPrice;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UnitsInStock", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = unitsInStock;
                command.Parameters.Add("@UnitsOnOrder", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = unitsOnOrder;
                command.Parameters.Add("@ReorderLevel", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = reorderLevel;
                command.Parameters.Add("@Discontinued", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = discontinued;

                rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();



        }
        return rowsAffected;
```

and code for exception handling is

```
protected void ProductGridView_RowUpdated(object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        Master.ErrorMessage = "Cannot Update Record";
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Master.ResultMessage = "Record Updated Succesfully";
    }
```

but still i am getting error :The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Products_Suppliers". The conflict occurred in database "NORTHWIND", table "dbo.Suppliers", column 'SupplierID'.
The statement has been terminated.
it had worked once ,but not working everytime.
And i am also getting Asp.net Validation of viewstate MAC failed error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is happening in the stored procedure being called in UpdateProduct so the event `RowUpdated` is never reached/called so you cannot "catch" that exception there.

Comment: actually it worked once ,but again started to show this problem.and already checked store procedure.Is there any chance the problem is somehow connected with the validation of viewstate MAC failed error.

Comment: A foreign key constraint error is not an ASP.NET error.  ASP is only returning the exception as provided by the call to ExecuteNonQuery. To "catch" the error in row updated you would have to wrap the ExecuteNonQuery calls in a try/catch to trap the exception and allow the function call to complete so that the RowUpdated event fires

Comment: what i supposed to do on catch exception ,because i am writing the code in class library file so i have not access to label for displaying the message.

Comment: You don't _have_ to do anything, maybe log the error, it depends on your needs.  The main reason for the try/catch is to capture the exception so it doesn't halt the application and allows the function to complete so the rest of the events fire, specifically the RowUpdated.